# Rails 4 / Ruby2 / PG9.3: ActiveRecord confuses tables on SQL subselect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

In my rails app projects are assigned to users via assignments. Now I want to retrieve the unassigned projects for a specific user. The SQL query:

`SELECT * FROM projects WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT project_id FROM assignments WHERE user_id = 1`

lists all the unassigned projects for user 1 when entered in PgAdmin.

Here is my rails code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :assignments, dependent: :destroy
has_many :assigned_projects, through: :assignments, source: :project
has_many :unassigned_projects, :class_name => 'Project', :finder_sql => proc {
  ["SELECT * FROM projects WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT project_id FROM assignments WHERE user_id = ? )", self.id]
}
```

This raises:

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - PG::Error: ERROR:  column projects.user_id does not exist
    LINE 1: SELECT  1 AS one FROM "projects"  WHERE "projects"."user_id" = $1`

which is no surprise, because the correct column would be "assignments.user_id". Apparently rails does not respect the second FROM. What is wrong with my code?

**Update:**
Inspecting the "unassigned_projects"-CollectionProxy reveals, that it contains *exactly* what it is supposed to contain. So it seems that it is first assembled correctly. However, afterwards PG raises the error, when calling:

```
if @unassigned_projects.any?
```

But not if calling:

```
if @assigned_projects.any?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out that the most efficient way to deal with this is to replace the deprecated has_many-finder_sql-definition with a class method for User:

```
def unassigned_projects
  Project.where.not(id: self.assigned_projects.collect(&:id))
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
["SELECT * FROM project WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT project_id FROM assignements a WHERE a.user_id = ?)", self.id]
```

Also, shouldn't the table be named `projects` instead of `project`? RoR usually uses plural forms for table names.

Finally, the correct spelling is probably `assignments`, without an extra 'e'.

Comment: Thanks you. Your answer probably points in the right direction. I changed the query accordingly, but I still receive the same error message. About the spelling: I'm not a native english speaker and misspelled "assignments" ;-). And of course the table is name "projects". The missing "s" is just a typo. I edited my post to fix this.